# EMV card reader application to Identify customers

Tags: c#, smartcard-reader, emv

EMV smart card reader:
I have used "1PAY.SYS.DDF01","2PAY.SYS.DDF01" and list of AID to read from EMV card. 
I want to read "card Id" or any tag represent unique value related to the card it self.but I can not notice any shared tag between them represent a unique value related to the card.

Note:
I don't want to make any payment process, Just I want use any tag to identify the customer using his card.

I found that the Tag "5F20" represent the cardholder name but not all cards I have read have this tag.

I used C# in my application.

Comment: AFAIK the EMV cards are identified by PAN + PAN Sequence number pair. Though it is strange to use bank card in such a scenario as banks spend a lot of money to teach their customers not to insert their bank cards into strange looking devices...Also remember that if you do not authenticate the card properly (SDA/DDA/CDA) it is quite easy to fool your system with a fake EMV card....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What do you mean by identify the customer ? Say card holder name is available, what are you going to do with it ? All cards have magnetic track on their back side. Have you tried to read Track 1, which will contain the card holder name ?

When you say an Id for a card, i think of card number. And payment cards are meant for payments. If you do not intend to do any payments why not look for an alternative. Btw, just reading and storing someones card data is not a good practice, and if at all you are doing, all sensitive stored data should be kept encrypted.

Comment: we are developing Kiosk for customer service, and we want to use the cards to identify the customer and we don't need any sensitive information.
I use electronic cards not magnetic. and I as mentioned I use  "1PAY.SYS.DDF01","2PAY.SYS.DDF01" and list of AID to read card info

Comment: Identify customer mean recognize the customer to provide special services for those customers

Comment: I use electronic not magnetic, I think in electronic card you read data using AID or  PSE so I doesn't read Track 1

Comment: Track 1 on the card has more chance of having a customer name and the process is much less complicated than getting from chip. If the mag stripe read capability is not available, then you can use card number tag 57(which is the track2, card number will be till delimiter) to identify the customer.

Comment: thank you so much for your response, but why in some cards I can not read the tracks but on the other I read them??

Comment: are there any limitation on read track, does  I need special permission or some thing like this

Comment: There are no limitations to get it. Do the below calls. SELECT, GET PROCESSING OPTIONS and READ apdu s and you will get track data in all cases. I you feel you have all what you need now, you can close the question with tick mark beside my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help,
The problem was in my code and after I review the specification of EMV v4.3 Book 3,  I found that the problem was when "Initiate Application Process" in Get Processing Options command in my code.

In EMV v4.3  book 3 Section 10.2 view the steps to read Application data.

also https://www.openscdp.org/scripts/tutorial/emv/
contain good examples to show how to use this APDU commands

Comment: yes they do have. most are in java script and you can read the logic so easily from the code. you are welcome.